# Modifying scrolling behavior in Flutter ScrollView

Tags: flutter, singlechildscrollview

I have a problem in `singleChildScrollView`. Below is my code:

```
return Scaffold(
 body:SingleChildScrollView(
  child:
    Column(
    children:[
    //...
    Container(height:500,child:listview.builder())
      ],
    //...    
    )),
);
```

What I want is to keep on scrolling the children of Column inside the `singleChildScrollView` when the items of `listview.builder` are ended. Alternatively, I cant even remove the `container` (the parent of `listview.builder`) it causes rendering error. If the question in not clear, please ask me. I'll explain. Kindly help :(.

Comment: Your question is not clear.

Comment: I dont want to stop scrolling the listview items. If the items of listview are ended, the swiping should scroll the children of singlechildscrollview.

Comment: Don't use more than one vertical scrolling view like SingleChildScrollView, Listview, it will cause unexpected scrolling behavior. Try to use physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics() with out your SingleChildScrollView or Listview.

Comment: @ZakariaHossain does that apply to my scroll issue then? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72747311/flutter-singlechildscrollview-is-taking-over-scrolling-with-child-mapview-widget